# Comparação de Data (status a vencer)

Tags: php

tenho uma data informada ($date_crl) e preciso mostrar um alerta em 3 condições:

Se date_crl for maior que 30 dias da data atual: VIGENTE.

Se date_crl for menor que a data atual: VENCIDO.

Se date_crl falta 30 dias ou menos para vencer: ALERTA

Estou com dificuldade para conseguir pegar esses 30 dias?

Comment: Como essa data está formatada? Você poderia colocar o que você já fez ou tentou fazer na sua pergunta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**exemplo - ideone**](https://ideone.com/v5iyzI)

A principal função usada no exemplo foi [**strtotime**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtotime.php)

> a data atual pode ser em qq formato válido desde que seja igual ao formato da data $date_crl

```
//Exemplos de formato data atual
//$dataAtual = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
//$dataAtual = date("d-m-Y");
//$dataAtual = date("Y-m-d");

$time_atual = strtotime($dataAtual);

$time_expira = strtotime($date_crl);

$dif_tempo = $time_expira - $time_atual;

$dias = (int)floor( $dif_tempo / (60 * 60 * 24));

if ($dias <= 30 && $dias > 0){
    echo "ALERTA";
}elseif($dias<0){
    echo "VENCIDO";
}else{
    echo "VIGENTE";
}
```

Comment: Certo, sua resposta me ajudou muito a descobrir onde estava errando. Fiz a alteração no IF e alterei o post

Comment: Certo, mas o ALERTA seria para 30 ou menos dias. Se passar da data, aí fica VENCIDO. Por isso usei o: `$dias <= 30 && $dias > 0`

Comment: Qual a sua sugestão nesse caso ?

Comment: editei a pergunta de modo que a edição que vc fez na reposta esteja de acordo com o desejado.

Comment: ah ta, valeu Leo!